# Is it possible to use Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity.Core with .net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

When I attempt to install Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity.Core version 2.2 with my .net 4.0 project I get the following error:

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.2.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I understand that it requires .net 4.5+.

Is there an older version of Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity.Core that works with .net 4.0?

More generally, where is the best place to check what version of .net a specific nuget package supports?

Comment: Why don't you upgrade the project target to v4.5 or lastest version?

Comment: @TânNguyễn there is a cost associated with that, I'm hoping to see if there is another way before I go down that road.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to check the target framework version on Nuget site. But if I were you, I will create a new project for testing, just install one by one to test for compatibility. There are 14 packages at all, so I think the time to test each package is shorter than the time waiting an answer here.